# Show helper texts to understand the functionality of a function in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, function, helper

I don't know the exact name of this features.

So, take a loot at this images:

[image]

After hitting "return" button,

[image]

I want to do the same things with my own methods.

- I want to show a short note along with my function (when someone type function name partially)
- I want to show clear texts like "condition", "code" instead of "xxx:Int", "yyy:String" with my custom function

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to create your own Code Snippet?

Comment: check this link: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-tips-creating-custom-code-snippets-in-xcode-d91facf5e242

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple. just type `_` before the explanation word. Have a look at this example:

```
func testExample(_ someExplanation: String){
}
```

and when you call this function it will look like:

> testExample(`someExlanation`)

---

**UPDATE**

There are a few nuances to different use cases, but generally an underscore means "ignore this".

When declaring a new function, an underscore tells Swift that the parameter should have no label when called — that's the case you're seeing. A fuller function declaration looks like this:

```
func myFunc(label name: Int) // call it like myFunc(label: 3)
```

"label" is an argument label, and must be present when you call the function. (And since Swift 3, labels are required for all arguments by default.) "name" is the variable name for that argument that you use inside the function. A shorter form looks like this:

```
func myFunc(name: Int) // call it like myFunc(name: 3)
```

This is a shortcut that lets you use the same word for both external argument label and internal parameter name. It's equivalent to func `myFunc(name name: Int).`

If you want your function to be callable without parameter labels, you use the underscore _ to make the label be nothing/ignored. (In that case you have to provide an internal name if you want to be able to use the parameter.)

```
func myFunc(_ name: Int) // call it like myFunc(3)
```

Comment: `func testExample(_ someExplanation: String)` shows `testExample(someExplanation: String)` and `func testExample(_ : String)` shows `testExample(String)`. But what I need is `testExample(someExplanation)` alone